# Creating extra column based on start/end date in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table with the enrollment information of our members that includes the start date and end date of their membership. It looks like the following:[current table format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yb027.png)

The goal is to have the data output in the following layout:
[desired data output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPv9F.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you would need to get the data from that table. Then handle it with an external programming languages like PHP or JAVA.

The algorithm would be like this:

1. get all start values and end values
2. merge them into an array
3. sort them by date
4. create a new table with the dates (create a database with the external code)
5. foreach member go through the date array and check if it's between the memberdates and directly set a 1 or 0 into the new table (sql update) or create a temp-array to prepare an insert.

That should work. I could write it for you if you tell me your code languages.